# How to link Github remote repository to preexisting local repository?

Tags: git, github

I recently switched computers and, in the process, uploaded a directory through Dropbox to the cloud. I want to access this directory from a new computer (which I can), but Github is no longer linked to repositories in that directory. Is there a way to link the remote Github repository to the directory on new computer, without deleting the unlinked repositories in the directory and re-cloning them?

Comment: See https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-remote.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub (the remote site) itself is not aware or linked to any local folder.

A Git repository should include in its `.git/config` file the remote repository url

```
cd /path/to/new/local/folder/copied/from/Dropbox
git remote -v
```

If not, that might mean you have copied only the sources without the `.git` subfolder, which means a new `git clone` would be needed.